# How can I insert a variable name for Allure Attachments titles such as Step or method name?

Tags: java, allure

I am using the Allure test framework for a Java project.
I am only allowed to use constants in the annotation when defining the name of the attachment.

For example:

```
@Attachment(value = "My Screenshot", type = "image/png")
public byte[] saveScreenshot(byte[] screenShot) {
    return screenShot;
}
```

Referring to the `value`, if I use this for multiple Steps they will always appear in the reports with the title `My Screenshot`.

How am I able to make it a bit more dynamic like the Allure `@Step` annotation, i.e. Use of parameters such as `{0}` and method name `{method}` in the string?

Comment: Also Allure can auto detect type of attachments with image, so you don't need to specify type in this case

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In allure 2.0 I've found that the `{0} {1} .. {N}` doesn't work.
It gives the error:

```
ERROR io.qameta.allure.util.NamingUtils - Could not find parameter 1
```

Instead you can use the variable name in curly braces:

```
@Attachment("Taking Screenshot because {whyIAmAttachingScreenshot}")
public byte[] saveScreenshot(String whyIAmAttachingScreenshot) {
    //take screenshot
}
```

Answer (score 5):

Attachments use same placeholders as `@Step` annotation.

- **{N}** where N is a zero-based positive integer that will be replaced by the Nth method argument value (0 corresponds to the first argument, 1 to the second, etc.).

  ```
  @Attachment("Taking Screenshot because {0}")
  public byte[] saveScreenshot(String whyIAmAttachingScreenshot) {
      //take screenshot
  }
  ```
- **{method}** will be replaced by the annotated method name.

  ```
  @Attachment("My Screenshot from {method}")
  public byte[] saveScreenshot() {
      return screenShot;
  }
  ```

For more information you can see [wiki](https://github.com/allure-framework/allure-core/wiki/Attachments).